# Flexslider not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I'm updating a wordpress site and decided to use Flexslider for the carousel, but the images aren't showing up. I know they're there, because I can see them in Chrome's debug console.

The site is here: http://in-iq-qa.co/

As you can see, there's the empty flexslider and another carousel beneath it being powered by unslider. I'm just trying to figure out why nothing is showing.

```
<!-- flexslider -->
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class='slideContentBox cover-stories cs-4 innovation-and-creativity spring-2015 z-featured-slider '>
                <a href="http://in-iq-qa.co/innovation-and-creativity/cover-story-4/"><h2>The Heart of the Matter</h2></a>

                <p>
                    Donald Casey Jr. drills down to the core of the constantly changing healthcare industry to discover the innovative ways Cardinal Health can position itself for dramatic growth and success.<a class="readMore" href="http://in-iq-qa.co/innovation-and-creativity/cover-story-4/"
                    title="Insigniam Quarterly links to: The Heart of the Matter">Read
                    More</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!--end .slideContentBox-->
            <img src="http://in-iq-qa.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/The-Heart-of-the-Matter.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Heart of the Matter | Insigniam Quarterly | Spring 2015" />                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='slideContentBox spring-2015 strategy z-featured-slider '>
                <a href="http://in-iq-qa.co/strategy/unleash-culture-to-fuel-growth/"><h2>Unleash Culture to Fuel Growth</h2></a>

                <p>
                    How to align the nine facets of corporate culture to drive performance.<a class="readMore" href="http://in-iq-qa.co/strategy/unleash-culture-to-fuel-growth/"
                    title="Insigniam Quarterly links to: Unleash Culture to Fuel Growth">Read
                    More</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!--end .slideContentBox-->
            <img src="http://in-iq-qa.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Unleash-Culture-to-Fuel-Growth.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Unleash Culture to Fuel Growth" />                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='slideContentBox spring-2015 strategy z-featured-slider '>
                <a href="http://in-iq-qa.co/strategy/growth-with-an-accent/"><h2>Growth with an Accent</h2></a>

                <p>
                    From cheeseburgers to lattes, John Dawson understands how to transform domestic brands into successful international enterprises.<a class="readMore" href="http://in-iq-qa.co/strategy/growth-with-an-accent/"
                    title="Insigniam Quarterly links to: Growth with an Accent">Read
                    More</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!--end .slideContentBox-->
            <img src="http://in-iq-qa.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/GrowthWithAccent.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Growth with an accent | Insigniam Quarterly | Spring 2015" />                            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='slideContentBox spring-2015 transform z-featured-slider '>
                <a href="http://in-iq-qa.co/transform/growth-through-adversity-transforming-disaster-into-untold-success/"><h2>Growth Through Adversity: Transforming Disaster Into Untold Success</h2></a>

                <p>
                    An interview with turnaround expert John Jastrem.<a class="readMore" href="http://in-iq-qa.co/transform/growth-through-adversity-transforming-disaster-into-untold-success/"
                    title="Insigniam Quarterly links to: Growth Through Adversity: Transforming Disaster Into Untold Success">Read
                    More</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!--end .slideContentBox-->
            <img src="http://in-iq-qa.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/growth-through-adversity.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="Growth through adversity | Insigniam Quarterly | Spring 2015" />                            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- /flexslider -->



$(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails"
    });
});
```

Comment: Slider is working,in your case it might be due to slow internet or css  and js may not loaded at the time you viewed. Cheers :)

Comment: @Ujjwal Could you take a screenshot and show me please. I've checked on multiple computers and devices and I'm only seeing the 2nd slideshow, not the first.

Comment: you have js errors in the console, flexslider is not loaded and you need to reference `$` with the word `jQuery` for no-conflict jquery (wp uses this).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your initialization code

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: "thumbnails"
    });
```

into the document.ready function instead of the window.load.  Not sure if that's it, but I can't see any other issues.  My guess is that window.load is firing before your flexslider javascript is loaded and it's not finding that function.